# Highcharts as an Out-of-the-Office calendar

Tags: highcharts

In the process of testing out if/how HighCharts can be used to display out-of-the-office info I started tinkering around with the following nice starting point example: http://jsfiddle.net/s4thS/1/

The result (see: http://jsfiddle.net/SvenHjerson/5ywEq/1/) looks already pretty good but I need some help with a few minor things.

1. When un-selecting a person (series), can the entire series be hidden
   rather than just hiding the data?
2. How can I get the tooltip to display the out-of-the-office period also between the start and end date (start and end works fine)?
3. How can I show some sort of "conflict" (series?) when the series that are still visible are ooto at the same time?
4. How can I get the crosshair to display all people's out-of-the-office?  I tried a few things with crosshairs but can't get it to behave as I would like. Looks related the the problem described in #2

   ```
   "crosshairs: true"
   ```

Are those limitation above maybe due to the fact that the example is using a "line" rather than a "bar" chart perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`tooltip.shared`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared) property. This will also mean changing your `tooltip.formatter`.
See this [update](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/5ywEq/2/).

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
    formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';

        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            s += '<br><b>'+ this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %e %b %Y', this.point.options.from) + 
            ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %e %b %Y', this.point.options.to);
        });

        return s;
    },
    //formatter: function() {
    //    return '<b>'+ this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
    //        Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %e %b %Y', this.point.options.from) + 
    //        ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %e %b %Y', this.point.options.to); 
    //},
    shared: true
},
```

Comment: Ok, when hovering over eg. "1 Jan" it now does show what I would expect (although with the people in reverse order) ... but when hovering over eg. "6 Jan" when Person 3,4 and 5 are out-of-office I noticed "Person 5" is not included?  The crosshair also acts a bit strange which seems to be because its looking for start and end-points only.

Comment: It looks to me like it is because you only have 2 points - the beginning and end of each span.

Comment: Indeed, the 2 points being the out-of-office start date and end date.  Is there no way to make Highcharts consider it as one date span?  Hmmm , what is the setting to "not show" the point symbols?

Comment: To not show the markers use `marker: {enabled: false}`: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.marker.enabled

Comment: @SvenHjerson - Ah, sorry. Yes, this is possible: add in in marker: `{enabled: false}, states: { hover: { enabled: false } }`. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/5ywEq/5/